# jQuery if/else statement, remove id

Tags: jquery

I have a new problem to the existing script:
Got the if/else to work and displace #id correctly. Now I want to add one more condition to check if the date is expired. My sample in jsfiddle works, somehow it didn't work in my actual staging site, the #id that suppose to display appear for a couple of seconds and then disappear.
Here is the [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dmsedgemarkets/xos9xqeo/)

Yes, I have jQuery included in the page.

Appreciate if any experts here could help me out.

===========

I am totally new to jQuery, appreciate if you could help me on the following:
I have the following tags in a page.
How do I remove #normal and show only #special or vise versa using if else statement if the page detects this attribute [href="/my/categories/happy] on document.ready

```
<div class="pane-content">
  <ul>
    <li class="taxonomy-term-reference-0"><a href="/my/categories/sad"> Sad</a>, <a href="/my/categories/happy">Happy</a>, <a href="/my/categories/joyful">Joyful</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="normal ">
  <h4>Normal</h4>
</div>

<div id="special ">
  <h4>Special</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: @Prs, thanks! Both scripts work like charm!.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with **[`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** method and [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```js
var ln = $('[href="/my/categories/happy"]').length === 0;

$('#normal').toggle(ln);
$('#special').toggle(!ln);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pane-content">
  <ul>
    <li class="taxonomy-term-reference-0"><a href="/my/categories/sad"> Sad</a>, <a href="/my/categories/happy">Happy</a>, <a href="/my/categories/joyful">Joyful</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="normal">
  <h4>Normal</h4>
</div>

<div id="special">
  <h4>Special</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Pranav, it works. Thanks a million. However, how do I use if/else statement to detect the page if [href="/my/categories/happy"] is found. eg: on document.ready, if  [href="/my/categories/happy"] found, display #special, else display #normal.

Comment: @emmm :  if(`$('[href="/my/categories/happy"]').length === 0){ /*.......*/ } else { /*......*/ }`

Comment: please see if this is correct https://jsfiddle.net/dmsedgemarkets/g4umgsqL/

Comment: @emmm : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..

```
if ($('a[href="/my/categories/happy"]').length) {
    $('#normal').remove();
} else {
    $('#special').remove();
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Spacific href found', $('a[href="/my/categories/happy"]').length == 1 ? true : false)
  if ($('a[href="/my/categories/happy"]').length) {
    $('#normal').remove();
  } else {
    $('#special').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pane-content">
  <ul>
    <li class="taxonomy-term-reference-0"><a href="/my/categories/sad"> Sad</a>, <a href="/my/categories/happy">Happy</a>, <a href="/my/categories/joyful">Joyful</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="normal">
  <h4>Normal</h4>
</div>

<div id="special">
  <h4>Special</h4>
</div>
```